# File upload ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, file-upload, extjs4

I have this field:

```js
{
    xtype: 'filefield',
    labelAlign: 'top',
    id: 'fileAllegato',
    hidden: true,
    margin: '0 15 5 10',
    fieldLabel: 'Allegato',
    allowBlank: false,
    blankText:'Il campo &egrave obbligatorio!',
    typeAhead: true,
    selectOnFocus: true,   
    anchor: '100%',
    buttonText: 'Allega'
}
```

When I load the file, I want to save it in db. The field does not belong to a form and, therefore, I can not do the submit. How can I do?

Comment: Why don't you surround it with a `formPanel`? You still can use CSS/inline style to make the form as transparent as if it does not exist (no header, no title, no border...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dummy form (without even displaying it). Something like

```
var f = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
   items: [ your filefield item ]
})
```

And then do submit.

Comment: it's good idea to create a dummy form but after add the filefield on dummy form it destroyed from it's current parent component.

Answer (score 0):

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'filefield',
    name: 'file',
    fieldLabel: 'File',
    labelWidth: 50,
    anchor: '100%',
    buttonText: 'Select File...'
}],
```

Live demo is [here](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-upload-to-asp-net-mvc-demo.html)